# HRegionServer shows "error telling master we are up". Showing socket exception: Invalid argument

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, centos7, bigdata

Iam trying to create a hbase cluster in 3 centos machines. Hadoop(v - 2.8.0) is up and running on top I configured HBase(v - 1.2.5).Hbase start up is fine it started HMaster and Region servers but still it shows the follwing error in region servers and in HMaster log it shows no region servers are checked in.

```
2017-04-20 19:30:33,950 WARN  [regionserver/localhost/127.0.0.1:16020] regionserver.HRegionServer: error telling master we are up
com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.RegionServerStatusProtos$RegionServerStatusService$BlockingStub.regionServerStartup(RegionServerStatusProtos.java:8982)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.reportForDuty(HRegionServer.java:2316)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:907)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:493)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:722)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:906)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:873)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1241)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:227)
```

**JPS of my master node**

```
[hadoop@localhost bin]$ jps
20624 SecondaryNameNode
20800 ResourceManager
20401 NameNode
18061 Jps
17839 HMaster
```

**JPS of myregion nodes are**

```
[hadoop@localhost bin]$ jps    
11168 Jps
482 DataNode
10840 HQuorumPeer
10974 HRegionServer
```

**hbase-site.xml of all nodes**

```
<configuration>
<property>
        <name>hbase.master.hostname</name>
        <value>NameNode</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://NameNode:8020/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>hdfs://NameNode:8020/zookeeper</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>DataNode1,DataNode2</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**regionservers file contain**

```
DataNode1
DataNode2
```

**etc/hosts file in all nodes contain actual ips rather than loopback ips**

```
192.168.00.00 NameNode
192.168.00.00 DataNode1
192.168.00.00 DataNode2
```

Note configuration is same in all nodes. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: RegionServer is bound to the localhost IP. Change the hostname of each node to its respective name as mapped in /etc/hosts.

Comment: Yes, I put the following  property in region server hbase-site.xml solved my problem.<property>
        <name>hbase.regionserver.hostname</name>
        <value>DataNode1</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hbase.regionserver.port</name>
        <value>16020</value>
</property>. Thank You :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the following property in all region servers hbase-site.xml solved my problem.`<property> <name>hbase.regionserver.hostname</name> <value>DataNode1</value> </property> <property> <name>hbase.regionserver.port</name> <value>16020</value> </property>`

Answer (score 1):

i was facing the same problem but...
changing hostname resolved my problem
`sudo hostnamectl set-hostname new_hostname`
i had a **master** and a node called **node1**
[link to wiki that have the configs](https://github.com/nimbo3/Keenbo/wiki/Change-Hostname)